# Understanding the "let" command

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions

From [this tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let) I was looking at the very first example and can't figure out why `b` would be set to `2`

```
$ let 'b = a' "(a += 3) + $((a = 1)), b++"
$ echo "$a - $b - $?"
4 - 2 - 0
```

From my understanding, `let` evaluates the commands from left to right. Thus, `b=a` is evaluated, but since `a` is blank at first, this evaluates to `0`, which I've tested with

```
$ let 'b=a'
$ echo $b
0
```

Next, `a += 3`, which, since `a` is blank, evaluates to `3`, but then we add `$((a = 1))` which to me seems to be setting `a` back to 1. Finally we add `1` to `b`. I would expect the output to be `1 - 1 - 0`. However, since the output is `4 - 2 - 0`, it seems to me like `$((a = 1))` is the first statement executed. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash parses the arguments given before they are passed to the command. In this case, the `$()` section is evaluated during this initial parse. The value of `a` is set to 1 and the whole section substituted with 1. So `let` sees:

```
b = a (a += 3) + 1, b++
```

and a is *already* 1 before that executes.

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial states `Remember that inside arithmetic evaluation contexts, all other expansions are processed as usual (from left-to-right), and the resulting text is evaluated as an arithmetic expression.`.
So first all oter expansions (subshells with `$(something)`) are processed, before rhe resulting text is evaluated as an arithmetic expression.